# pgfplots groupplot: fillbetween breaks alignment of plots

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots, fillbetween

I recently (foolishly) updated all my TeXlive packages, including pgfplots (from 1.10 to 1.11).

I now have an issue with the groupplots and fillbetween libraries, where using the fillbetween library 1) doesn't work and 2) breaks the alignment of the group plots.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween,groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis group left]

\begin{groupplot}[%
group style={%
group size=1 by 2,
vertical sep=0pt,
x descriptions at=edge bottom},
width=11.5cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=-1.8,
xmax=1.8,
/pgf/number format/use comma,
xlabel={Y [mm]},
]
\nextgroupplot[height=2.49166666667cm,ylabel={Z [mm]},y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.08,.5)}},ymin=-0.59,ymax=0.19]

\nextgroupplot[ylabel={$\kappa$ [mm$^{-1}$]},y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.08,.5)}},ymin=-12,ymax=8,height=6cm]
\addplot[color=green,solid,name path=mittemin] coordinates {(-1.8,-10)  (1.8,-10)};
\addplot[color=green,solid,name path=mittemax] coordinates {(-1.8,-1.5) (1.8,-1.5)};
\addplot[color=green,solid,name path=randmin]  coordinates {(-1.8,0.9)  (1.8,0.9)};
\addplot[color=green,solid,name path=randmax]  coordinates {(-1.8,6.5)  (1.8,6.5)};

\addplot[green!20] fill between[of=mittemin and mittemax];
\addplot[green!20] fill between[of=randmin  and randmax];

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This yields the following result (no filling, broken alignment):

[image: broken alignment]

After commenting out the (non-functioning) `fill between` statements, the alignment is right again:

[image: correct alignment]

This hasn't occurred with pgfplots 1.10. Setting `compat=1.10` does not change the output. As far as I can work out, something was changed in the fillbetween library for 1.11, is this a bug or am I missing something?

**EDIT:**
I downgraded to pgfplots 1.10, which fixed the problem (for anyone with the same issue: uninstalled the old version via `tlmgr`, downloaded it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgfplots/files/pgfplots/1.10/pgfplots_1.10.tds.zip/download), unzipped it to `TEXMFLOCAL` and ran `mktexlsr`). The issue therefore seems to be related to pgfplots only, I am going to ask Christian Feuersänger about it.

Comment: The alignment in 1.11 is fixed if you add `anchor=south` to the groupplot options. Filling requires some more investigation indeed.

Comment: Any news on the filling problem? I have a similar issue.

Comment: I've run into this problem with groupplot and fillbetween a couple of times, when I try to place an axis with fillbetween next to a groupplot, My usual fix is to place a "main anchor node" first thing in my tikzpicture, and then anchor the groupplot to this node. I never need to align my other axes to my anchor node - as long as I do this with the groupplot, it seems to fix it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug in pgfplots that is fixed in version 1.13.

Comment: I still do have that issue in 1.13...