# Vertical alignment of pgfplots groupplots with uneven number of plots

Tags: pgfplots, vertical-alignment, groupplots

I'm trying to produce a 2 colums by 2/3 rows groupplot in pgfplots. On the first column I have 2 plots, on the second I have 3 plots. I want to distribute the plot heights for the side with fewer plots to have the same outer bounding box.

[image: Uneven number groupplot with vertial alignment problem.]

Using two different heights for the first and second column plots I can, at least somewhat, make them fit in total height. However, vertically the first row is aligned on the centers of the two first-row plots (a & b). What I want to achieve is, that the bounding box top of the first row is aligned vertically and the bounding box bottom line is aligned for the last plot.

I found `anchor=north` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200619/pgfplots-groupplot-fillbetween-breaks-alignment-of-plots), but it changes only the right plot's position (b), that is then aligned with the left vertical center (of plot a). Even if I add the option for both plots.

My code looks somewhat like:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
% pictures drawn with TikZ
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots} % needs to be loaded exactly like this
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\heightLarge}{4.7cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}
[
group style={group size=2 by 3, % cols by rows
    horizontal sep=50pt,
},
  width= 0.385\textwidth,
  height=3.2cm,
  xmin=0,
  xmax=14,
  xlabel={time in s},
]

\nextgroupplot[% #1
  ymin=0.0,
  ymax=2/2,
  ylabel={a},
  height=\heightLarge,
]
\addplot[]{sin(x)};
 

\nextgroupplot[% #2
  ymin=0,
  ymax=0.2/0.03,
  ylabel={b},
]
\addplot[]{sin(x)};

\nextgroupplot[% #3
  ymin=-0.8,
  ymax=0.8,
  height=\heightLarge,
]
\addplot[]{sin(x)};
    
\nextgroupplot[% #4
  ymin=2.5/3,
  ymax=4.2/3,
]
\addplot[]{sin(x)};

  
\nextgroupplot[group/empty plot] % #5

\nextgroupplot[% #6
  ymin=0,
  ymax=60,
]
\addplot[]{sin(x)};
    
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that `groupplot` can be used to make a layout like this. Luckily it is not too difficult to do manually.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
xmin=0, xmax=14, 
xlabel={time in s}, xlabel style={yshift=4pt},
}
\begin{axis}[
name=plot1,
width=5cm, height=5cm,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
]
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
name=plot2, at={($(plot1.south west)+(0,-1cm)$)}, anchor=north west,
width=5cm, height=5cm,
ymin=-1, ymax=1,
]
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
name=plot3, at={($(plot1.north east)+(1.5cm,0)$)}, anchor=north west,
width=5cm, height=3.5cm,
ymin=0, ymax=6,
]
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
name=plot4, at={($(plot1.north east)!0.5!(plot2.south east)+(1.5cm,0)$)}, anchor=west,
width=5cm, height=3.5cm,
ymin=0.5, ymax=1.4,
]
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
name=plot5, at={($(plot2.south east)+(1.5cm,0)$)}, anchor=south west,
width=5cm, height=3.5cm,
ymin=0, ymax=60,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Five empty graphs in a grid]

**Edit:** A layout with seven graphs

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1, width=5cm, height=3cm}
\begin{axis}[name=plot1] \end{axis}
\begin{axis}[name=plot2, at={($(plot1.south west)+(0,-2cm)$)}, anchor=north west] \end{axis}
\begin{axis}[name=plot3, at={($(plot2.south west)+(0,-2cm)$)}, anchor=north west] \end{axis}
\begin{axis}[name=plot4, at={($(plot1.north east)+(1cm,0)$)},  anchor=north west] \end{axis}
\begin{axis}[name=plot7, at={($(plot3.south east)+(1cm,0)$)},  anchor=south west] \end{axis}
\begin{axis}[name=plot5, at={($(plot4)!1/3!(plot7)$)},  anchor=center] \end{axis}
\begin{axis}[name=plot6, at={($(plot4)!2/3!(plot7)$)},  anchor=center] \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Seven graphs in a grid]

Comment: Wow, yeah, thanks! This is exactly what I needed. Coud you give me a hint how to realize the same thing for 3|4 rows? Since the middle two are the height-separation value apart I tried to put them 
`at={($(plot1.north east)!0.5!(plot_last_left.south east)+(\horizontalSeparation,\verticalSeparation/2)$)},`, but using the height 5cm, verticalSeparation 1 and height right 3.5 the plots are not distributed equally spaced.

Comment: Preferably it would be calculated from the height of the left side plots and the vertical separation (equal for both sides). I tried
`\pgfmathparse{(3*\heightLeft-\verticalSeparation)/4}
\let\heightRight\pgfmathresult`, but it again produces results that are not of equal height. Also I cannot seem to think of another quantity that I could anchor the `at` of the middle two rows on the right.

Comment: Count the number of graphs and the number of spaces in an interval. -there is not always the same number, so carefull considerations are needed. You are not forced to use the `($(plota)!1/3!(plotb)$)` notation - you can calculate by hand the position of the plot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works now. I used plots below each other on the right and centered the left middle position.
What I don't understand though, is why the calculations and therefore the distances don't add up: I use 3.5cm height for the right plots and 1cm vertical separation, which makes 17cm total height. If I use 5cm height for the left plots their vertical separation is not 1cm, even though this would also add up to 17cm.

Comment: I do not want to try to figure out, what you are doing. Remember `width` and `height` are for final dimensions by default. To set dimensions of the axis box, set option `scale only axis=true` for all `axis`. -or ask a new question, so I can see your code.

Comment: Take measurement with e.g. `\draw[red, ultra thick] (plot7.south east) -- +(0,3.5cm);
`

Comment: Thank you very much. The measurements showed strange axis heights/widths and I found that the `scale only axis=true` setting was not properly set in my document wide figure settings file. Thanks again!